# How to configure proguard in Eclipse Me for generating jar(FFI) file for j2me

Tags: eclipse, java-me, proguard, ffi

i am creating FFI(jar file) for j2me. i want the jar to be optimized and obfuscated using proguard. How can i configure eclipse for above process. i have shown the path of proguard lib and enabled the obfuscation but it didn't work. is there any other configuration i need to do.   Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Mobile Tools for Java? https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.sequoyah.mtj

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helio and plugin for j2me.

Comment: Please, read this article http://developer.samsung.com/java/technical-docs/Java-ME-Obfuscation-Packaging-using-Eclipse